# Does opening up the Stack Overflow app count as visit?

Tags: support, android-app, ios-app

I'm just curious if firing up the Stack Overflow app for android counts as visit on Stack Overflow.

I'm asking because I'm trying to get the "whatever crazy count consecutive days in row nerd on so" badge (again).

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: I would guess it does if you're logged in

Comment: I would think with your rep, you would realize that this is off-topic for SO.

Comment: How should I? I could if I risk to loose a day now. Otherwise it just shows me that I was there today, because once I login via web it counts as.. Yeah visited today.. I get what's the problem, right?

Comment: Also, read tag descriptions before tagging. This is not what stackoverflow should be used for on this site.

Comment: BTW, you're really good at pissing off @codeMagic, an impressive feat in of itself.

Comment: Also, welcome to Meta-Stack Overflow @Walialu ! You probably should have visited sooner. ;-)

Comment: @CarlAnderson yep, but this way I lost my virginity on getting down voted like a boss 

Comment: Only 3 downvotes - you're not trying hard enough :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, accessing the site via the app [does count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193269):

> We're now counting access to a site via the app for both "last seen"
>   and the "daily site access" for the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges.
>
> As is true with the sites, we don't actually count all access; only
>   those actions we consider "real". For the mobile app, this basically
>   means accessing the feed doesn't count; we'll probably tweak what we
>   consider "real" over time.

Comment: No it doesn't. I just reset a 10 day streak because i used the app yesterday!