# Stack Overflow now has its own app on iOS and Android

Tags: discussion, android-app, ios-app, stack-overflow-app

## TL;DR:

Today we launched a new mobile app specifically for Stack Overflow. It lets you view, post, vote, and comment on Stack Overflow questions and answers. Download links are included in this post.

## Huh? Don’t we already have a mobile app?

Alert readers may notice that you can already do all of those things on the Stack Exchange app for iOS and Android, for Stack Overflow and for 175 other Q&A communities. This new app has just about the same functionality, but it’s available for folks who just want a Stack Overflow mobile experience (or who search their respective app marketplace for “Stack Overflow”). We hope this will make it more straightforward for developers who don’t use Stack Exchange much  to read, write, and manage programming questions and answers on mobile.

If you’re interested, both the iOS and Android versions are available today:

- [Download on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-overflow/id1155618808).
- [Get it on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.stackoverflow&utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=meta&utm_campaign=gen-so-mobile-app). The Android app is currently in beta. All of the functionality is working, but we are making small tweaks to the user interface.

To learn more about the app’s features, [read our blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/16/stack-overflow-official-app-launches-ios-android/).

Feedback on the existing Stack Exchange apps should continue to live on MSE. But, please report bugs and request features for the new Stack Overflow apps here on MSO:

- [Give Android feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-app)
- [Give iOS feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-app).

Bug reports and the like should become their own questions in those tags, but we welcome general questions and feedback about the concept of the Stack Overflow app in the comments and answers on this one. What do you think?

Comment: So, is this simply a branding issue, or are there any other reasons to split the apps this way? And do you expect the features of the apps to diverge?

Comment: Will some features remain available only on the web app?

Comment: And the old app? Not a single bug was fixed in over a year, not a single request was done, or even responded to. 100% ignore rate. (android app only, iOS app does have a developer)

Comment: @MadScientist Branding is the biggest thing, yeah. The Stack Exchange apps just don't get as many downloads a day as we'd expect an app belonging to a company our size to get. We're hoping that more people will look for "Stack Overflow" on the app store.

Comment: @Mistalis currently the only thing remaining on the web app is moderator functionality. We will either add more functionality into the apps, or double-down on making our mobile-website faster and better, depending on how this launch goes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272419/310230) (*See edit 12/12/16*).

Comment: That's because the app just stinks. Man do I love this network of sites, but come on - the app is just no good. I know it's a "only enough humans to go around" thing, but don't you guys think diverting even one or two more people to help you could work wonders?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not going to lie and say our Android app has gotten the love and attention it needs in the last year. But, this app is built in a shared codebase with the SE app (albeit UI changes still need to be ported) -- the biggest changes made to the SE android app have been secret early access programs which I can't wait to talk about after I/O :)

Comment: @Seth I know. I read it. Nothing was done since then, not a single tiny action. (Which was expected)

Comment: @patricksweeney More workers = Higher investment (*time/money*). Why would a company (*which is precisely what Stack Overflow is*) invest money into something that doesn't hold any significant return value?

Comment: @Seth - oh I agree, but I'd extend that to "Why did they build it in the first place?".

Comment: @ShadowWizard Might be that they've been putting their ressources into the Stack Overflow app. Not sure though.

Comment: @patricksweeney I'm not 100% on that, tbh, but I think that having a mobile application is benefitial for several reasons (*exposure via google playstore, comfort etc.*), yet investing a lot of dev time into it isn't really worth it, it's not going to significantly affect the number of users, at least not significantly enough to justify the investment, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Seth you're on the money, in both messages :) We've been working full time on the SO app since last June, and while I'd _love_ to grow my team and hire more people and invest more in the apps, it doesn't make sense to when the SE app's numbers are ones I would've killed for back in my start-up days but a tiny tiny % of total company numbers. I'm _really_ hoping this app is a blockbuster and causes us to double-down, but in 6 months my team might be doing mobile-web if that helps the company more.

Comment: What about the Windows Apps?

Comment: Does [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272254/does-opening-up-the-stack-overflow-app-count-as-visit?noredirect=1&lq=1) still apply? :o

Comment: We want a chat on mobile. We started working on an Android version, but an official one would be incredible.

Comment: @JoshYates1980 According to a statistic from oct '16, germany, the market share of windows phones was just above 2%. I think that the investment would be too big to justify it, given the small audience.

Comment: I think what would really be cool is a SO chat app.. Thanks!

Comment: The chat on mobile would be awesome.

Comment: @Seth yep, the same caveats apply about "real actions" but both the SE apps and SO apps go through the same back-end code route for handling that.

Comment: I'd expect for the app to be able to report bug/feature request directly from it (just like SE app let the user posting it on MSE), but since MSO is not accessible on SO app, do you have thought about this?

Comment: @AndrewT. yeah we've been talking about this. We considered adding a "Report Bug" button to the More tab but then the current list of bugs needs to be browsable for duplicates which would require Meta browsing. For the first version it was easiest to just say "Only the main site", but it's on our mind now.

Comment: As for iOS, wouldn't it have been easier to add "Stack Overflow" to the keywords of the Stack Exchange app listing instead of creating a new app?

Comment: Installed it, found no way to filter questions by favorite tags. Uninstalled.

Comment: @TJ I suggested that here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349258/feature-request-filter-questions-by-tag

Comment: I can't log in with Facebook. It just tells me there was and error logging in.

Comment: @Fogmeister there seems to be an issue in our Facebook login code, we're looking into it and can hopefully fix it without an app update.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi ok thanks for letting me know :-)

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi fixed already :D

Comment: Why should anyone be at least 17 years to download this app?How are my future kids supposed to learn?

Comment: Looks like the new app only lets you search questions? The old one searches both questions and answers. I like seeing new answers in the results. I'll stick with the old app.

Comment: Personally I would love to be able to do reviews on the mobile app

Comment: @TristanWiley I'm going to be launching an Android app for chat soon-ish. Hang in there. It won't be official but it will mirror nearly all of the functionality of the desktop site with notifications, etc.

Comment: I think the whole "app" thing is silly. Just make good mobile sites, I shouldn't have to leave my browser to do every little silly thing in a much worse way. It's rare I ever use a websites app for anything unless it has functionality that utilizes the actual hardware features of the phone, like streamlining photos with the camera in the Ebay app or fingerprinting for banking. In general the whole make apps out of everything sucks. Let me stay in the browser where I can do all the things. The app has to be better than the website for me to use it!!!

Comment: Why didn't you just rename the other app to make it more searchable?

Comment: From the blog; "For now, the two apps have nearly identical functionality.". It took one year to essentially rename the app, with no improvements? Why not fix the SE app and tag it with stackoverflow when publishing..?

Comment: First time seeing this a moderators post was massively down voted.

Comment: which stack did you used ? react native ? nativescript ? or pure java & objective c ?

Comment: @Shashanth hell yeah !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does using the Stack Exchange app count for the visit badges?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256086/does-using-the-stack-exchange-app-count-for-the-visit-badges)

Comment: Oh wow, tough crowd. Can't really comment on any of this, never having used the app. Don't think the "no one needs a mobile app" argument holds water, though. Famously, our #1 user, Jon Skeet, uses his 1-hr commute (IIRC) to answer questions before starting the work day. (Or at least used to a couple years ago; don't know whether he still is in the same job.)

Comment: @Shashanth `First time seeing this a moderators post was massively down voted.` you should have been here when Jeff Atwood, our founding father, was still around :D :D :D

Comment: I don't think people are annoyed that we have a mobile app, I think they're annoyed we have ANOTHER mobile app that doesn't actually bring anything new (in fact it actually has less features) than the current one on the app stores - plus while they've released this stripped down version of the app for branding issues, they've still yet to fix a lot of the now 'old' version of the android app which is not getting updated. This is from what I've gathered so far though and not in any way throwing my own opinion out there @Pekka웃

Comment: Why is an app needed for Stack Overflow? The mobile version of the website got also a lot of possibilities and features. I think the app is just a clone of the mobile website. So why sould I download it? I use Stack Overflow most on my computer and not on a mobile device. The future is the web and not (native) mobile applications. [Look at this graph of the SO survey 2017](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#developer-profile-developer-type) 72.6% are web developpers and only 23% are mobile app developers.

Comment: Interesting in theory, but only once you make the app work for moderation activities. I don't dev on my phone, but I'd be interested on moderating on it or reviewing on it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I too never have been using it myself but I have seen terribly formatted unreadable questions and answers posted from it, followed by complaints from their authors that they can't find a button to delete this trash. Haven't you?

Comment: ...overall, app seems to be closely following [Spolsky style](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/839601 "eplained in details eg here"): make it easier to post garbage and make it harder to get rid of it

Comment: I don't have access to the Google Play store in China. Is there an alternate download site?

Comment: I would have thought a website for *computer programmers* could avoid doing the spammy applications marketing technique. Ah well. The times we live in...

Comment: Not to be snarky but are we saying that in 2017 the best brains behind web standards and development are not able to produce a mobile version of a web page?  There's some stuff you can do on a browser on a linux laptop which you can't do on a browser on a linux (based) phone?  What, exactly?  Are the problems being addressed?  It seems bizarre.  Html5, javascript, css...what am I missing?  Handling the small size is a problem - is that it?  Are the apps being developed for non-technical reasons (experimentation, marketing)?

Comment: I'm amazed by the numerous negative comments here - so far I had a very good experience with the SE iOS app - I use it almost every day mainly to go through recent Q&A in SO and TravelSE. I once reported a bug that was fixed in couple of weeks with a [good explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288886/link-to-the-recommended-job-is-broken-in-the-mobile-apps) of what was causing the bug - the new app seems to be handy, I'll give it a try and eventually replace the SE app with this one.

Comment: I do like the rich editor experience for the mobile app offers. And how commenting is handled. But the mobile web interface is *so much more powerful*; I mainly use the app(s) to get notifications. I *used* to use the feed to preview notifications in context (usually I need to respond on my laptop), but the feed refresh results have been very spotty of late (latest notifications not showing up even when I restart the app). So the mobile apps don't fit my use-cases.

Comment: Is reusing the existing [ios-app] and [android-app] tags for this really the right move? There are old questions here about the S**E** app that use those tags. How should SO users ask questions on Meta.SO about the S**E** app? (Remember that the official, frequently restated Meta policy is that no user should feel compelled to post on the network Meta: local Metas are fine even for things that are global.)

Comment: Hey, am I really the only person who loves the old iOS app?! I use it everyday and it is awesome!

Comment: Do you guys ever heard about windows phone and desktop(8, 8.1, 10) app development.

Comment: So when do you plan to roll out individual apps for all the other Stack Exchanges?  Why are you splitting effort?  I'm still not seeing a compelling explanation as to *why* you need 2 apps.

Comment: @Caimen I disagree with "apps are silly" for one reason - notifications. I have the SO app (and SE app before it) mostly to get notification of responses in comments, new answers, etc. A mobile website is very important too, but they are no good at notifications.

Comment: @DanLowe websites can send notifications even if the site is no longer open. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221203/send-desktop-notifications-in-chrome-or-firefox-from-a-closed-web-app

Comment: So let me get this straight, instead of fixing and improving the existing app you're just going to build a new app that just does SO? That's as infuriating as when Facebook ripped out messaging and forced people to use Messenger. I will not use this app strictly out of principle.

Comment: @NathanOsman I'd love to see/hear about it, mind if I shoot you an email?

Comment: I'm with a lot of people here. 1) Fix SE app first; seriously at least respond to requests. 2) If SE was working 100% why would we even need a SO app? 3) Are we going to get hundreds of site specific apps now? That seems like a waste of resources to me.

Comment: You don't get a lot of Android downloads because the Android app is **broken**.  Seriously, nigh *unusable*. Therefore, I really can't take this justification seriously.

Comment: @Ajean I don't get it. How would someone know how well or poorly the app works without downloading it and using it? Am I missing something? Or maybe I just misunderstood what you meant by downloads.

Comment: @AlexisTyler That question is for desktop, not mobile - I was talking about the iOS app. There's no way for mobile web sites to send notifications AFAIK (at least, not in iOS).

Comment: @Don't Word of mouth (or in his case word of internet). If the app is good, people will recommend it on the main site. If it's bad, they'll say don't bother using the app it's terrible. Therefore the only hits they're measuring success by are brand new users to Stack Overflow at all, so that plus countless ignored bug fix requests make me think that they're doing this for the predominantly bad user base rather than the established users that actually care.

Comment: And just to be clear, I don't think all new users are bad. But judging success by number of downloads without attending to bugs is just silly to me.

Comment: At least you made one good decision and kept Stack Overflow in the main app! Now, start actually updating the **main** mobile app!

Comment: The new app is so wonderful that you have to spend time to find stuff such as *Ask question* button. I agree with all the comments in this thread. This app could have been made much better. All the features in that could have been added to this app instead. I think  it was major resource wastage done by team. They should still improve this app.

Comment: @Pratik well, they fixed two bugs in the old android app today. Two whole bugs, after years of not doing anything. Guess that's a start.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi - Please don't feel discouraged by this post, people are just blowing off steam, and that is not addressed at you or the app (it's obvious but it should be said). It is good that the app is revived. Thanks!

Comment: Can you revert the "Read this post in our app!" link to go to the regular app? I don't feel like being an involuntary beta user.

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery in your app? :p

Comment: Is the goal app downloads? Or app usage? Don't optimize the wrong thing...

Comment: is this app an open source?

Comment: It is very difficult for me not to interpret announcements like this one and all the stuff on Documentation as a big "FU" to the veteran Stack Overflow users who have been around a long time, contribute *massive* amounts of useful content to your site, and are the real reason why new users come and keep coming back here. We've been complaining over and over that there are serious quality problems on the Q&A side, but there is no evidence that anyone is actually working on this. Instead, lots of money is being spent developing things that don't benefit anyone and don't improve the core product.

Comment: Case in point, [nearly a year ago, I was told that there was internal work being done to improve the Ask Question page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page#comment361289_326868). Yet *no changes* have been released, nor has there been any further attempt to solicit input from the community. From my perspective, it looks like you guys no longer care about improving Stack Overflow, which I can't help but interpret as a very strong signal about your respect for veteran contributors and the things they think are critically important.

Comment: *the biggest changes made to the SE android app have been secret early access programs which I can't wait to talk about after I/O* - well I/O is over now @KasraRahjerdi, can you talk about these new features yet?

Comment: The apps [no longer exist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373307/6471538). Voting to close as can no longer be reproduced.

Comment: This question is now the second most downvoted question on SO Meta. The first is a feature-request question asking to add in things like paying SE money to remove part of a user's rep.

Answer (score 230):

I hate to say this but...

I stopped using the SE app some time back. The app experience is geared towards Q&A and that ecosystem. That's good. But to try and do anything else ranges from confusing to downright terrible. Chat isn't available. Moderation is often an afterthought.

I found the mobile version of the website to be far superior. I can see Close votes again. I can use Chat. Unless this improves on that, I won't be using it.

Comment: Which means the app is not needed right ? They should scrap it ?

Comment: @HtmlTosin I'm saying that the app could be made out of HTML5 and do at least the same job the website does. Right now the app tries to recreate them from scratch

Comment: Actually, the app uses the API, which uses far less data than mobile. But, I digress. The only think I miss on the app is the reopen and duplicates.

Comment: This. As a moderator the only thing the app is useful for is the notifications/pings. Everything else (including chat) goes through Chrome for mobile. SE/SO app should be geared toward power users, and power users already know that SO is part of SE. Fix the app's usefulness, you'll fix the app's download stats.

Comment: I do use the app, but only so I can see notifications for messages. And recently the feed refresh has been.. hit and miss. Everything else while on the phone is done in the mobile web view (with occasional forays into the desktop view if I need to see moderator-specific stuff).

Comment: @Braiam That's merely an implementation detail and isn't necessarily true for apps vs mobile pages in general..

Comment: @MartijnPieters So it is a pager, not an app. Welcome to the 90s!

Comment: @AnderBiguri: a pager with a good rich editor, but I don't really use it find new questions to answer so the editor is under-used.

Comment: @Mat'sMug It depends how we're defining "power users", but I don't think we'll ever be able to justify a whole mobile team on an app used only by a small number of power users. Flip it around the other way: if we had 3-4 devs to throw at problems for power users, we would not decide that their top priority was building an app. To justify native mobile apps, we have to find a bigger audience for them.

Comment: @DavidFullerton fair enough, but how do you collect usage stats on features that aren't implemented? what's the average reputation score of SE app users? do they have access to review queues? edit privs? close vote privs? trusted user privs? do they have notifications enabled? FWIW **your power users *are* the bread & butter of this website**, without them EVERYTHING falls apart. Who cares if a million 1-rep fly-by askers download the app every day? Shouldn't the users you're doing this for be the users that stick around and can/want-to help with content moderation?

Comment: I mean I *want* to use the app - but I constantly have to switch back to Chrome because too many features are missing. So I end up with the app running in the background buzzing me when I get a ping, which I handle in the browser because if I handle it in the app I'll be switching to the browser anyway because the ping came from SE chat or requires me to take an action that's not implemented in the app. This makes the SO app completely redundant, at least from my perspective. Not going to run 2 apps on my phone just to get the exact same notifications I'd get with the SE app.

Comment: @DavidFullerton Look at what the users are saying on this post though. We are asking how nearly a year was justified to create a near duplicate application. We are throwing shade at that effort because we've posted bug reports that have been ignored, we've asked for more functionality, access to moderation tasks, and mobile chat all via your existing application. An application that supports the entire network. These are features your existing user base wants and bugs we have reported. Instead of focusing on that, we were given a less functional duplicate.

Comment: @Andy You're right, it wasn't worth a year. There's a long, sad story here, but it was originally expected to only take a few months and... well, here we are a year later. We decided to go ahead and launch and see what we can learn, and we'll reassess from here.

Comment: @DavidFullerton I really really hope that what you learn from this should be that you need to **fix the bugs**. You are effectively *ignoring* some of your most important user base, which is something that the company keeps saying they don't do, but then .... they do.

Comment: @DavidFullerton "a few months"?  How long would it have taken to just rename the SE app and see if that gets more installs?  You're using [this loop](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/0*cVN4S759QpD1kJN0.png), getting [these results](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/0*Uq_KxRVSyvVRLzFc.png), when you want to be in [this one](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*YNkWVnIh5lwqAU8uzWC4nQ.png).  (Images from [here](https://library.gv.com/the-gv-research-sprint-a-4-day-process-for-answering-important-startup-questions-97279b532b25)).

Comment: This topic is much like the one about whether [documentation has failed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348030/82548), a deservedly vocal response to the disregard shown to the users of the given tools, ignoring the reported bugs, flaws and feature requests in favour of assumptions,  optimism and a strange "Field of Dreams" style faith in the mantra of "*if we build it, they will come*." Like the documentation I also don't use the app, because the mobile site does what I need it do (barring push notifications, and that one app feature doesn't justify the download and installation).

Comment: @DavidThomas In both cases we are trying to grow *beyond* our current product & user base. We *are* listening to users, but as long as we're trying to reach a new audience we're going to sound a little deaf to people who say "Stop doing new things and just focus on improving what you've already got". Documentation missed the mark, but there's still a good problem in there that we want to tackle.

Comment: @DavidFullerton, if I post a meta question asking about usage stats for the mobile apps, would you (or a member of your team), be willing to find some numbers? It would be similar to another pending data request I've posted recently: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349204/has-the-top-bar-redesign-met-its-goals

Comment: @Andy Yes, we can share the usage data we have on our mobile apps.

Comment: @DavidFullerton That argument would fly a lot better if people were actually saying what you way they are saying. What we're saying is what you've got now is *broken*, so what it needs is *fixing* not *improving*, and I've never run across anybody that thinks that fixing bugs and creating new things are mutual exclusive.  Developer hours are limited, I understand that. I can even understand spending more time, percentage-wise, on new stuff than on bug fixing. But as far as I can see, the amount of time spent on fixing the bugs has been not low, but **zero**.

Comment: @DavidFullerton "*We're trying to grow beyond our current product & user base*" - so, you're telling us, that fixing bugs/features/whatever's on the current app is *less* important than creating an alternate app with *fewer features and site support* in hopes that people will start **miraculously** understanding that it's the correct app and download it? Isn't that hoping for a bit much? Would it not have been easier to rebrand the existing SE app as SO, make SO the default site and go from there? I really don't understand what actual *business* motives were in this move.

Comment: This answer: +137, this question: -137

Comment: @DavidFullerton I've posted the request [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349353/mobile-app-usage-stats).

Comment: After trying to unsuccessfully use the SE app for a week (even posting answers is difficult); I gave up today and uninstalled it. Using mobile website is much more smoother.

Answer (score 149):

Just to be clear ... You sunk one year (not quite, but eh) of dev-time into a bad<sup>1</sup> searchability clone of an app? Instead of finding out why the app isn't downloaded as much as you'd expect, you commit something in the ballpark of 100k$<sup>2</sup> in resources on the idea that your expert users, generating great content, are "unable to find the app"?

I'm not ever going to search Stack Overflow on any app, if I can help it, because it's near impossible to get any useful results from my teeny tiny mobile screen.

I'm not ever going to search Stack Overflow on a tablet either, because at that point I'm most probably close enough to a device with a screen that allows me to do useful things **besides** searching for one thing on Stack Overflow.

The point I'm trying to make is ... be aware of who your target audience is and what they want. Aside from the developer survey this year, where I answered a single question on the app (whether I use it, that is), I haven't seen any place where feedback regarding the app is meaningfully processed. (I mean there are bugs in the app from literally years ago ...)

Instead of asking your audience what they want (power user tools, less bugs), you just went and assumed stuff and it looks like you got a rebuke for it ...

Unless of course, the app is actually meaningfully different (as in better for a certain kind of work) than the current SE app, and you just didn't get around to actually make it different yet, which seems far fetched from my current POV :/

> <sup>1</sup>This question scores -23 at time of writing, it's not possible to browse any site but SO (according to question), [it's not even possible to accept an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349270/stack-overflow-app-on-android-can-i-accept-an-answer), ...
>   <sup>2</sup> ["[..]We've been working full time on the SO app since last June, [..]"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android#comment473543_349255)

Comment: Judging from SO salary calculator, the ballpark is probably closer to $250K

Comment: Maybe I am missing context, but we probably shouldn't be assuming dollar figures like this. It doesn't seem likely someone spent their entire week every week for a year working on this one project. I am usually juggling 4-5 projects and I find that experience to be fairly typical among developers I know. Linear time != hours spent on a single project.

Comment: @DanLowe I'm referring to a comment by the Mobile Team lead on the post in a "footnote" attached to the dollar figure. ... Adding some usual numbers relating to cost for a junior dev for a month * 12, give or take a few from my homecountry, which equates to most probably quite a bit less than what they actually pay their mobile lead, I'd say it's a **very** conservative estimate... Plugging in the numbers from the (openly accessible) SO Salary Calculator makes for numbers in the same magnitude, and then some ...

Answer (score 132):

## Will you please stop "working" on unimportant bullshit like this app and focus on things that actually matter?

Yes, the Stack Exchange team, you read that right - **you're wasting time, manpower, and (perhaps most importantly) money on things that nobody cares about.** What's worse, **you're not even aware of it!**

- Instead of trying to fix [a trainwreck in which almost no one has faith](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation), you could actually listen to [what people suggested for SE Quality Project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285889).
- Instead of [paralyzing Meta for a whole week because Joel didn't want to make a blog post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440), you could [stop Triage from using Help & Improvement as a toilet bowl](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332546) by changing ONLY ONE STRING displayed on ONLY ONE PAGE ACROSS THE WHOLE NETWORK.
- Instead of [polishing the top bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337745/were-soon-to-be-a-b-testing-some-changes-to-the-top-nav), you could [start migrating to HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time) FOUR PRECIOUS MONTHS earlier.

And now you're duplicating the entire official app based on the false assumption that people searching for "stack overflow" instead of "stack exchange" can't find out that there's an official SE app! **That app is already the first result for "stack overflow" on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=stack+overflow) *AND* [App Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNhR5.png)!**

Please, stop this madness.

## Please, rethink your priorities and order your [to-do list](https://stackexchange.com/filters/245531/bugs-feature-requests) based on actual feedback instead of wild guesses and whim.

---

Now let me make a guess.

**You're wondering what could be worked on *right now* instead of duplicating the official SE app for Stack Overflow.**

Here's a non-exhaustive list of what you could do:

- [Give new users more help with following our almost unacceptably arcane rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285903)
- [Let people more precisely explain why they used a certain close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210314/categories-other-than-off-topic-should-allow-custom-close-reasons)
- [Let trusted users delete unambiguously bad questions with prejudice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287910/pre-register-delete-vote) (don't you dare to assume most question askers are willing to improve their questions)
- [Do something about hope-eradicatingly bad questions that somehow don't fit to any close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261858/reviewing-some-awful-questions-is-just-a-waste-of-time-can-we-have-a-no-commen)
- Make it easier to close bad questions by [making close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248312/swing-the-gold-hammer-even-more) [more powerful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4) and/or [giving super-high-rep users more CVs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266500/proposal-to-make-close-votes-scale-with-rep)
- [Do something about non-answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285924)
- ## [BUFF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284764/does-the-quality-filter-work) [THE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346518/turn-the-quality-filter-back-on) [QUALITY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286930/disallow-entire-questions-from-being-entirely-bold-italic-all-caps-or-linked) [FILTER](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264266/if-a-question-is-in-all-uppercase-or-all-lowercase-our-quality-filters-should-a)! PLEASE!
- Get back to [Project Reduplication of Deduplication](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286329/project-reduplication-of-deduplication-has-begun)
- [Make people close duplicates instead of answering them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions)
- [Make it easier to find duplicate targets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285953)
- If you will insist on keeping Documentation running, then at least make some use of its hidden gems by [using topics and/or examples as duplicate targets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328658/will-there-be-a-close-reason-for-covered-in-docs)
- [Do something about horrible answers that somehow get upvoted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314157/can-we-do-something-about-old-outdated-terrible-highly-upvoted-answers)

Comment: While I'd have put it more politely (and I disagree about some of the points, and can't offer an opinion on the app) some bullet points here *do* make a lot of sense. Probably the wrong place to air them, though.

Comment: Seriously though.  How is it possible that SO is failing [Joel test #5](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) *so hard*?

Comment: I appreciate that there are a lot of issues on Stack Overflow that need to be addressed, and maybe we haven't been responding to them as quickly as we should. But Stack Overflow Q&A is a big, established product, most of the problems left are hard, and we can't let maintenance become the *only* thing we work on or we'll just slowly run out of money and go out of business. We are trying to both maintain Q&A *and* solve new problems for developers and reach new audiences. The latter is hard, and maybe we'll fail on a lot of our ideas, but we're not going to stop trying.

Comment: Didn't know `bullshit` is [OK](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=bullshit) here until this post!

Comment: While I also would have put it more politely and I can't weigh in on all the suggestions, I think this level of frustration is what a lot of us are feeling right now.

Comment: @DavidFullerton Why are you going to run out of money and go out of business maintaining an existing product, as opposed to creating entirely new products?  I would think that neglecting your only largely successful product, and alienating and your most valuable users of that product, is a good way to run out of money and go out of business.

Comment: @Servy We don't have a sustainable business model yet. Even if we did, we'd have to keep inventing or we'll eventually become obsolete. See [The Innovator's Dilemma](https://www.amazon.com/Innovators-Dilemma-Revolutionary-Change-Business/dp/0062060244).

Comment: @DavidFullerton The app is free, so I'm not seeing how it's improving the monetization of SO.  Are there some hidden fees in there that I'm not aware of that result in it generating more money than the same consumption of that content would on the regular website?

Comment: @Servy If it's successful we can add Jobs, Dev Story, ads, etc. Getting new users to participate in new ways is a good thing (as long as they're not being destructive). That's why this app is not targeted at power users.

Comment: @DavidFullerton So you're assuming people that don't, and will never, use the actual website will find this app, and use it, exclusively, to interact with SO? That seems odd to me; I don't expect that to be a good introduction to SO, or where programmers are going to go when looking for answers. If you're treating the existence of the app as nothing more than an advertisement for SO in the app store, then I'm surprised that that's the most economical form of exposure out there.  There have to be simpler and easier ways of getting attention, or improved traffic, to the other existing products.

Comment: @DavidFullerton *"Getting new users to participate in new ways is a good thing ... That's why this app is not targeted at power users."* - What? No. This 'app', which you claim could be the 'savior of our woes', **can't even accept an answer.** Tell me, please, *how is that acceptable?* You want *new* users to use this app and interact with the site, but the funny thing is these new user *cannot* upvote, which means the only thing they have is an 'Accept Answer' button, but **it's not there**. This app is a direct encouragement for people to ask a question and *not* give back to the community.

Comment: @EBrown Accepting was clearly supposed to be in there, that is a bug we'll fix ASAP. We did call it a "beta" :)

Comment: @DavidFullerton ***How did that pass Q/A?*** That's my point. You guys half-assed this app, then tell us it's 'ready for public testing' but manage to omit one of 5 (yes, 5) major features. I'm not pissed we're getting an app we don't want, I'm pissed that we're getting an app we don't want, missing *critical* features. The disrespect with that is *astounding*. I get it, the 'regular' users are not your target audience, but you *literally* and *actively* made our lives more difficult. The **only** good thing is it's going to be fixed 'soon'.

Comment: @dorukayhan - You have *some* good points there, but I strongly disagree with the way you're presenting it. This is not nice, awfully demanding, and reads like you know for certain what would work and what wouldn't (IMO many of the things you've linked would only have a minor impact). Also, [what Shog9 said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348143/7586) - it's probably good to have a small team experimenting something new. These are not your (or the community's) time, resources, or money to allocate (by the way, I thought the top bar and developer story were quite nice).

Comment: At the end of the day, SO is a company. They want to do things that make them money so they can keep providing the site to an ever increasing number of visitors. Projects like this increase page views and user engagement, which in turn generates more revenue.

Comment: The tone of this post is quite rude. I do understand your point, but sadly it is overshadowed by the tone. It is human nature to be more forthcoming in a constructive discussion so I think the post could gain value by reducing some of the emotional fire.

Comment: @Rhayene It's not remotely overshadowed by the tone; you just don't like it.  I happen to like it as do other mods and users. It's refreshing to occasionally read real people expressing real emotions in an industry full of corporate dweebs "reaching out" and "moving forward" like so many blind cave animals.

Comment: @DrEval I personally don't care for the tone, but I _do_ like your impression of "reaching out" and "moving forward", two phrases I'd be quite happy to never hear again. Thanks for that imagery.

Comment: @DrEval it is not about liking or not liking. If you want to achieve something, then framing your point in a constructive tone is far superior to framing it like a rant. If you have a customer - for whom would you rather work overtime: the one that cooperates in a constructive way, or the one that screams at you? That point aside, I was also worried if this still fits the 'be nice' policy.

Comment: The owning will never be the same. I stand in awe. Respect.

Comment: @Rhayene and if you continually frame everything in this fuzzy-bunny speak for a couple of years and most of it is ignored, what do you do then? Keep pretending you're a Hugh Grant character, or get angr in the hopes a different approach might yield a response? In my world it's the latter

Comment: @Clive The consequence of being too emotional is that you are not taken serious anymore - and that quite fast. (I had that happen to me a lot of times, getting angry never had the result I wanted). I agree that a different approach is helpful when you are stuck, but being rude is not.

Comment: It's just your opinion that this is rude @Rhayene, at least 58 people disagree with you so far. I'm on mobile, haven't checked the swing of votes, but clearly vastly more people agree with this sentiment, and how it's been expressed, than don't. So I guess it's not "too emotional" after all, and is definitely being "taken seriously". If you don't like the tone that's fine, but don't try to suggest it's in any way incorrect or improper, or that the fluffy approach is somehow superior. 'Cos it's not.

Comment: @Clive it seems that we have a different image of what politeness, patience and respect is. It may be a cultural thing.

Comment: @Rayhene Perhaps; personally I'm fed up of the "everything offends me and I'm going to make that everyone's problem" culture. I find it hard to have patience for people who deliberately assign a lower value to an obviously good point, based solely on the way it's phrased. It's illogical, and speaks volumes of a wider problem in society. This post is not impolite, impatient or disrespectful, and it irks me that people fling words like that around when they're not warranted. Most of that is not aimed at you personally, evidently I needed to get that off my chest :)

Comment: @Clive I honestly think using words like 'bullshit' for someones else's work is disrespectful and unnecessary. But as I said it may be a cultural thing as I come from a background where acting professional is valued high :) I didn't want to devalue the point of this post - quite the contrary. I wanted it to shine, because it seems important.

Comment: Yeah, swearing doesnt bother me @Rhayene, I was taught early on that it's the person listening who chooses to give such words any negative power, not the person using them. It's not that simple, obviously, but that idea certainly helps to shape my perspective. It's much easier going through life _not_ being offended by the small stuff, I'm very sure of that

Comment: @DavidFullerton These changes in *user observable behaviour* are not "maintenance*.

Answer (score 84):

It didn't have to be this way. Maybe it still doesn't.

I understand the app being low priority if it wasn't getting used much and development resources were slim. But throwing manpower at a duplicate project when the one power users needed was languishing in bugs was not a good idea. Many of us have nearly abandoned using SE on the go because it's so frustrating.

If branding and searchability was the problem, I dare say most of us would have preferred see the existing app be rebranded to primarily serve SO with other sites buried in the UI somewhere if it meant getting some basic bug fixes in place so that normal site functions worked once you picked your site. Being a die hard SE user and having my app issues ignored for a duplicate project focused on newbies seems like the opposite of what drew me to SE in the first place. At this point I can [barely type through the crashes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346243/313192) but the development resources go to a duplicate?

If you'd updated the existing app to give power users something they didn't cringe when they had to use it I dare say it would have taken off faster in general. It might not be too late, but don't wait too long to get these projects back under the same roof. Two half baked apps doesn't do anybody any good. If the new app is better, hurry up and get it connected to all the sites. If the old app model is the future, hurry up and fix it so the basics work and the workflow isn't so cumbersome.

Answer (score 48):

I think your CEO [said it best](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/):

> 5. Do you fix bugs before writing new code?

This new app falls under the "neither need nor want" category. Why not fix the existing app first? Why add more code when the existing code is full of bugs and missing features?

I will also add that your own app is ranked below *Quora* when searching for "Stack Overflow" on the Google Play store. Why do we need this app, again?

[image]

Comment: And hey, the Stack Exchange app is right there!

Comment: To be fair, this is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mzJG.png - there are multiple 3rd-party clones and clients with similar logos and name. If I don't know that Stack Exchange is, it looks like just another unofficial app. The real logo stands out.

Answer (score 35):

I'm a bit "confused" about the thinking behind this decision. Especially because you guys at Stack Overflow are, at least in my opinion, known for making reasonable decisions with a good impact on the site(s) by adding new features (Documentation, Jobs, etc.).

Even if the Documentation isn't liked by all users, it still provides some functionality for some users.

But this move is, as much as I understand, just a marketing move which will most likely not work how you would have expected. 
As many others already mentioned, not many of us use the app at all, because we use the site on our big screens at work.

I predict that this app will not be downloaded more than the old one because the Stack Overflow users will not use it more often than before and also all the other user from other Stack Exchange sites will obviously not use it.

A waste of time and money which could have been used in a better way by, for example fixing some Android bugs (as it looks like, the app isn't useable currently).

*Written in the Stack Exchange iOS app*

Comment: Note that Documentation [is far from a reasonable decision with good impact](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348030/is-documentation-a-failed-experiment) in the eyes of many users.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I know, but there is still a new feature which was created. This new app doesn't provide any new functionality to the user at all.

Comment: Whether this will "work" depends on how many people are searching the app stores for "Stack Overflow" and not finding our old app. If there are a lot, then we'll see organic growth in the app and can start adding more features like Documentation, Dev Story, Jobs, etc. But we didn't want to spend another 6 months developing those features before finding out if anyone will install it.

Comment: +1 for the "Written in the Stack Exchange iOS app"

Comment: @DavidFullerton the fact that the ultimate goal is to "*[add] more features like Documentation, Dev Story, Jobs, etc.*" makes me wonder; perhaps it's just that the meta crowd (a lot of whom are quite opposed to Documentation, Dev Story, etc.) shows a correlation in dislike. Perhaps the target audience is not on SO.

Comment: @DavidFullerton What if I told you that the official SE app is the first hit for "stack overflow" on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=stack+overflow) and [Apple's App Store](https://i.imgur.com/r7F2JOr.png)?

Comment: @dorukayhan Yes, we made sure that Stack Overflow was prominent in the SE app description so that it got ranked for that. However, we still found that users did not know that was Stack Overflow and so didn't install it.

Comment: I'm really curious who these non-tech savvy SO users are who couldn't find the SE app... btw, the SE app is one of my favorite apps

Comment: I had [a similar question about the top bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343325#comment444539_343228), @DanBeaulieu. SE definitely sees a different user base than we here on Meta do.

Answer (score 31):

This is actually a question in the form of an answer phrased as a statement, but what the heck.

Just open source the gdamned thing on https://github.com/StackExchange and start taking pull requests.

You know Stack Overflow is a website with millions of software developers who are active regular members?  [You know](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017) that mobile devs are the 3rd largest self-identifying type of developer on SO, that they're the third largest group looking for work (aka folks polishing on their resume)...

You're leaving this great resource untapped. Tap it, get the app in ship shape order in much less time, and make everybody (well, not me, but still) happy.  Or happier.  Or happy-ish.

Comment: But now I'm curious what it would take to make *you* happy, Will. Apart from a globally ubiquitous hardware-based solution for slapping select Stack Overflow users, that is.

Comment: I'll be happy when MS stops trying to destroy their own mobile platform.

Comment: FWIW I talked with our lawyers last year or two years ago about opening sourcing the apps and where it got down to was "we could if you want but taking user code changes in will be a mess" and the idea of doing code drops not open sourcing didn't appeal to me.

Comment: *"taking user code changes in will be a mess"* I can't really speak from the development side, but I've followed enough major open source projects that do this to know it's not as bad as you think it is.  Many projects have strict contribution guides (that are open source themselves, if you get my drift) that let you decline pull requests easily if they don't meet those requirements outlined in the guides.  And you can always put up the very smallest, lowest-priority but still annoying bugs "up for grabs" while you work on the big stuff.

Comment: Agreed! Where can we "petition" to get this open-sourced?

Answer (score 23):

I'm an active *every day* user of the Stack Exchange iOS app. And I have to say it's pretty cool: no distractions, no ads, just questions and answers, almost all features the main site has are included, quick to use (tap the icon and now you're here!), awesome design, great usability (which I can't say about the mobile site, but that's just my opinion), etc. However, there are some bugs that have been around for quite a while (not days or weeks, but *months*), and nobody seems to be taking care of them, like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287914/code-view-issues-are-still-here).

But it won't be *nearly* as cool if there were no access to other sites in the SE network! It's always interesting to browse the hot questions from other sites, thus learning a lot of stuff, you can join any other site and ask questions there in literally one click. Because Stack Exchange isn't *only* Stack Overflow, it's *more*. Why restrict people to Stack Overflow *only*?

Comment: Well, I imagine this app isn't intended for people who are significant users of other sites. They have another app to use.

Comment: @Joe, and this is the problem. Why create an app dedicated to Stack Overflow, if there already is one that lets one access all the SE sites, Stack Overflow included? One could've created a separate app for each SE community for that matter. Looks like a waste of time & money to me. Also, personally I'm not (unfortunately) such a significant user of other sites, but I still browse them very often and find lots of cool information there.

Comment: @ForceBru Well, I think there is a case to be made that a separate app is not wholly unreasonable - not _this_ app, but an app.  One that has better programmer-centric features, like an easier time entering code for example, or integration with Documentation.  Stuff that doesn't really make sense on the SE overall app, which has to be much more generic since it's focused on a wide range of sites.

Answer (score 15):

I'm apparently somehow in the narrow niche of users who finds the Stack Exchange iOS app useful. I may be a niche of one, who knows, but I do.

My use case for it is specific: I use it to

- Receive notifications on my phone when someone responds to me in some way
- Reply to those notifications when it's a simple reply and I'm away from my desk
- Very occasionally, to glance at 'hot questions' when I'm bored.

Those three things the app does fine. It's not something I'm going to use to write long answers. It's not something I'll ever use to browse questions. I'm not closing questions. But for dealing with the quick pings, it's quite useful.

I think understanding the point of the app - that it's never going to be the *main* way you interact with Stack Whatever, but rather that it's the way you do very specific things that you might want to do on mobile - is key.

I don't see much of a point in a separate Stack Overflow app, though. It doesn't serve my niche effectively - I mean, maybe a few people will find it that didn't before, but app store SEO is not *that* hard is it? I guess if you want this to be sort of the 'developer preview' build of the app that's fine, but I don't see the branding making much sense.

And I don't see Stack Overflow being sufficiently special that it makes sense to have the app work substantially differently, unless you optimize the keyboard for code entry? If you *do* make changes that are optimized for Stack Overflow's community specifically, I'd probably put that in the question here...

Comment: Also my use case.

Comment: I have it purely for the inbox notifications. I never use the actual app, other than by mistake.

Answer (score 13):

Stack Overflow isn't *just* Q&A's. It's a *community*. There's a *culture*: the entire Stack Exchange network is *community-moderated*. It's that culture that polarizes a bunch of people about SO/SE; it's also that culture that makes SO/SE so successful - SE sites aren't your everyday discussion forum. You don't walk into SO with a blatant "gimmeh teh codez" question if you want to have a good day.

*It is known*.

To include more people, all SO/SE needs to do, is *keep being that* - and keep the content quality high. Which is hard to do without the power users with the required privileges to enforce that.

Take first-time users by the hand and walk them through a brief summary of the rulebook with a 2-minute interactive presentation (a bit like the [tour], but not *just* about site/app mechanics - i.e. an *actual* "tour": the term "Minimal Complete Verifiable Example" shouldn't be first encountered in a comment by someone that just voted to close your first post), and then *progressively unveil the functionality* as their reputation score increases and new privileges are acquired: that *gamification* element is also *fundamental* to SE.

*This* is what the SO/SE app mobile apps should capture and convey: by including tools for each relevant privilege level as features.

And *then* you could give users the ultimate incentive to download and use the SO/SE Official app: get someone to suck it up and do whatever it takes to fix the swag inventory management and have in-app purchases for SO mugs, tees, hats, keychains, stickers, pens, *whatever*: just shut up, charge the shipping fees, a 75% markup, and take my money. It's good for the economy; good business for the swag suppliers, and a constant flow of cash from avid users and die-hard fanatics that demand nothing more than throwing their money at you... if you'll let them.

But in-app purchases aren't the real driver (or even necessary): it's implementing the `score++ == tooling++` relationship in the app, that encapsulates the essence of SO/SE and gets you a central coherent backbone to implement features against. You avoid overwhelming new users while giving your more experimented faithful users the tools they worked so hard to unlock.

By implementing the tooling associated with reputation score, you teach new users that download this app *exactly* what SO/SE is about: they get to have this HUGE knowledge base in their pocket, and they're a part of it, and the more they're a part of it the more it's theirs to protect from bad content.

Sounds much like the website? Mission. Fucking. Accomplished.

Answer (score 10):

From observing both this new app and the older Stack Exchange app - which I've been using for years now - I get the impression that this hits the 80% use case.

Effectively, they help out with the primitive functionality of the site:

- Look at questions
- Search questions
- Get notifications (including rep changes)
- Flag and close questions*
- Voting
- Commenting

...which is what the site is used for 80% of the time.

The other 20% is noticeably absent:

- Moderation tooling - including being able to see close votes - is lacking
- No chat functionality
- No review queues

But here's my argument:  **it doesn't need to be there.**  Most of the site isn't geared towards these things; power users are easily outnumbered by less-power-users, and this app doesn't cater to power users.  Chat isn't that popular and so it's not included in the 80%, although I won't deny having that functionality would be cool.  It's likely a cost-benefit trade off for not including it.

**Bear in mind, I'm making my own arguments here**, but I'd even argue that a mobile variant of the website wouldn't be designed or engineered to cater to power users either, since what you want to accomplish or the information you want to fetch doesn't lend itself well to bandwidth concerns.

I use moderation tools, and I've had some pain points when editing or posting on the mobile site, but I have had to identify where and when I use this app.  I don't use it to get a whole bunch of copy editing done, nor can I really use it to hunt down duplicates (the exact coordinates thing is a pain point that I'll raise as a bug later), but if I want to look at questions and potentially answer them later, it's useful.  If I want to see when someone pings me, it's helpful (because I can then [relay that to my desktop](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302606/1079354)).

Please folks, don't hate on the app because it doesn't deliver the exact niches you use.  For its necessary purpose, it does it well.

Now, [can we have the same design for the old app, too?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296060/175248)  I bounce between communities more than I ever have before and I'd like my experience to be consistent.

<sup>*:  I hate exact coordinates.  I want fuzzy coordinates.  This may be a limitation of the API, but the API needs updated.</sup>

Comment: This answer is probably what the announcement should've been. Kudos -
 very insightful. Speaking as someone who does a lot of power-user stuff from my phone (moderation, approving user deletions, changing site settings), the mobile site is something I end up turning off pretty quickly; the information and tooling I need just isn't there. That doesn't make it bad, just makes it *bad for me*.

Comment: I'd guess that more than 80% of SO use - in particular by non-power-users - involves copying and pasting something between the site and an IDE/text editor.

Comment: If they made "Get notifications (including rep changes)" [work in the browser of your choice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android/349271#comment474024_349255) would you still use the app, as opposed to the browser version?

Comment: @Peilonrayz:  Oh, absolutely.  I mean, a service working capable of showing me the notifications in my browser would be *phenomenal*, but that wouldn't stop me from my other use cases; casually skimming questions to answer or to take some preliminary action of voting, commenting or closing.  I mean, I'm not going to open my laptop up on the bus *just* to vote on a question, y'know, so the app still has value.

Comment: @Makoto I meant as opposed to a mobile browser, :) As you can do those things in it, and some of the more 'power-user' stuff too.

Comment: @Peilonrayz:  Not sure if you missed my minor diatribe on a mobile version of the site.  I don't like it all that much since it mushes too many things together, so I'd find myself using the app more than the mobile site.  UX is important.

Comment: What would the bandwidth/data cost and the increased app footprint in MB be if chat support were included, I wonder? That'd be interesting to know.

Comment: @TylerH:  You should also consider the cost of making chat more flexible in that arena.  I doubt just embedding the existing chat client would be suitable, and that's also one part of the site that has design vestiges of 2011 left over.

Comment: @Shog9:  I suppose it also doesn't help that it was announced on Meta, which is, quite literally, where power users hang out.

Comment: @Makoto No I'm curious specifically about the cost to the user, not about the cost to the developer.

Answer (score 8):

Three quick points of review (this is regarding the iOS version):

1. Splitting notifications: I get why you chose to do this; actually I can't think of any other reasonable way to make it work. But I have no desire to get a system-level notification for an SO comment when I'm in the SE app. It also doesn't make much sense to me that comments from other sites are even displayed in my inbox in the Stack Overflow app, if the app is supposed to be all about *just* Stack Overflow. (Plus they switch me to another app.)
2. The raw /questions feed on Stack Overflow is a *firehose spewing lava*. /questions is usable on other sites, but not on Stack Overflow. Subject areas are too varied, and questions come in too fast. I need quicker access to my favorite tags (and/or [a "front page"-type view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229706/add-a-front-page-like-tab-to-the-ios-apps-main-site-view)). They're buried under the "More" tab; not discoverable and not easy to get to even once you know where to go.
3. I just noticed the "Open in Safari" button on posts is <del>not available</del> hidden under "Share". Switching to the browser is important as long as moderation stuff like reopen votes, suggested edits, and related questions/duplicate search aren't available in the app. This should be a top-level action.

(Also, [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349276/can-we-have-meta-support-with-the-new-stack-overflow-app).)

Overall, I don't really understand the motivation for this. I use the existing SE app (again, iOS<sup>*</sup>) on a daily basis. Far and away, the site I'm most active on is Stack Overflow, and the SE app works quite well for quick/casual browsing, basic moderation, and the occasional post. Plus I don't get switched away to another app if I want to view a message that's from a different site.

**As a primary Stack Overflow user**, I have no interest in this new app. I'm going to stick with the SE app unless the new one gains some greatly expanded feature set that's lacking in the older app.

---

<sup>*</sup>I hear that the Android app is somewhat less usable.

Comment: Good feedback. I gotta take issue with your footnote though; the Android app is *infinitely* better than the iOS app. In my exhaustive tests, the latter persistently refused to even launch on any of my devices, while the former ran on all of them with only minor hiccups.

Comment: I think you should count it as a success that you were even able to _install_ an iOS app on an non-Apple device, @Shog9.

Comment: Gotta confess, it took some doing. You'd think apple would make this easier!

Answer (score 6):

I think I could understand how SO app makes sense if it would be purely pragmatically motivated, for example like as follows:

> SE app is currently troublesome in too many ways and we want to make sure that its improvement is prioritised in a meaningful way.
>
> For that, we decided to release and maintain a version of the app with limited functionality which is expected to be in most demand.
>
> Specifically, this new app is going to focus solely on features that are substantially important for Q&A at the main site in the network - Stack Overflow.
>
> In particular, new app is *not* going to support features that are unrelated or insignificant for its primary purpose, such as:
>
> - MathJax support
> - cross-site authentication and joining other communities
> - i18n
> - hot network questions
> - chat
> - spoilers
> - per-site configurable settings
>     (eg rate limits, quality filter, and beta privilege thresholds)
> - Jobs
> - Documentation
> - meta (hm?)
> - etc...
>
> We expect that tight focus and rigid limiting of features will help us make better progress in resolving quality issues in the app.
>
> Fixes and improvements in the new app are expected to be backported to SE app when possible.

Quite a pity that per my reading of the announcement it doesn't look like the case here.

Granted, there is a small note that may be related but it's buried deep in the middle and appears to be totally obscured by other points: "make it more straightforward for developers who don’t use Stack Exchange much".

Answer (score 5):

I am pretty happy with my mobile's Chrome app where I just type the URL and can see the page quicker than the Stack Exchange app. I never needed a specific app just to browse Q&As or answer any post, and I don't know about other tasks though.

If an app is really needed (which I don't think) then please make a [progressive web application](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/).

Comment: Not sure how tech preference comes here.. but I would have gone with a  chat app suggestion..

Answer (score -16):

All those devs doing dev on (not for) phones and tablets can now finally get the answers they need!

Oh wait, no one does dev on phones and tablets because you have to use a desktop to do dev for phones and tablets. Who was the target audience for this?

Comment: Probably those who mostly _answer_? For example, I can run a Python interpreter in my head to answer questions. And if it's not enough, I've got one on my iPhone so I don't need a computer to stackoverflow.

Comment: I **do** dev on phones and tablet.

Answer (score -27):

While I do agree it seems funny to spend so much time on something that duplicates existing functionality, perhaps I can offer some perspective:

Perhaps people are wasting time by developing Emacs when we already have Vim?

Perhaps people are wasting time by developing Linux when we already had Windows?

Perhaps people are wasting time by developing Firefox when we already had Internet Explorer?

Perhaps people are wasting time by developing ARM CPUs when we already had Intel?

Perhaps people are wasting time by writing software when we can already get through our daily lives?

So the guy spent some time working on an app for you. Nobody stands to lose from this, It won't prop up anybody's self esteem here to tear them apart from trying to make a valuable contribution to Stack Overflow, which it could probably use with a little outside the box thinking.

I think it's a little tasteless to call people out for 'wasting time' and suggest better ways they could be investing when you are spending your time writing a novel on why they are wasting their time. When I get into a new environment, I write a *Hello, World!* program as a sanity check. Solving problems makes you a better programmer. Not everybody gets to work on space shuttle code straight out of college so if they want to make an app I don't see an issue with that.

Comment: These are horrible analogies! Every single thing you list is an instance of competition — different entities throwing different resources and expertise at a problem. Competing products can be good when they increase the amount of resources involved in solutions and motivate innovation. Browser development projects move along faster when a competing browser is biting at their heals. But that's not the case here. **SE used one pool of employees and resources to develop a competitor to themselves** — the result of which is two products each only half as good as one would have been. Maybe less.

Comment: microsoft used to make a unix variant for pc alongside their dos implementation. Think bigger. If somebody sees something they want to make and they do it it's really sad to see people get their underwear up in a wad because of it. What's it to anybody except the people that did it? Who cares? ThAts what I'm saying. Also, I think the analogies stand for themselves. If you choose to disregard their relevant aspects in favor for their irrelevant aspects then that's up to you. I don't think you can speak for alternate futures well enough to be the oracle of what could have been. Don't speculate

Comment: I hate all of these analogies (except for the first).