# Filter questions by tag on new SO app for Android

Tags: feature-request, android-app, stack-overflow-app

*Please note this is referring to using the search on the new Stack Overflow mobile app for Android.*

Currently you can filter by how active they are, how many votes they have or the newest questions, however I don't this is particularly useful for us developers who only feel we can help out with a specific language / framework.

Having a filter to first find all questions in a tag and then filter through these by the activity/votes/newest would be far more effective.

Comment: Can you not currently do this? On the iPhone app you just put `[whatever]` in the search bar.

Comment: This already exists

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'd want to be able to search for a question title without having to specify the Android keyword at the start of each search. Would be much more useful having the ability to filter by tag first and then search for a particular question.

Comment: I fail to see the benefit of having to set a filter, then type a query over just typing a query that includes the tag filter.

Comment: @KevinB I can't see this on the Android Stack Overflow app, could you screenshot it for me?

Comment: To be fair, I hate typing brackets and other non-letters on a touchscreen keyboard.  An alternative to the search box (which you have to know the syntax for) would be helpful.  Not sure if there's enough space on the app though.

Comment: @TinyGiant the benefit being that the app could remember your preference for tags to show instead of having to type them out every time you do a search. Plus you could show multiple tags without having to specify them all in the search bar

Comment: That all exists on the desktop version of the site. The mobile site is limited for... reasons.

Comment: I'll definitely add "My Tags" options to that drop down soon. Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi where will you be able to change the "My Tags" filter?

Comment: That's also accessible: `intags:mine`.