# Stack Overflow app on Android: can I accept an answer?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app, stack-overflow-app

Is there a way to accept an answer to one of my own questions in the new Android app?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how important it is to distinguish between Android or iOS for the Stack Overflow App but as long as the Android App is still a thing i don't think the tags should be used interchangeably. So for now I retagged  to the recent created tag

Comment: @rene in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android, it was specifically requested to use the android-app and ios-app tags. See "Give Android feedback" and "Give iOS feedback" towards the end.

Comment: Ok, I'm not going to fight that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this! This is fixed as of an update going live now. It'll have the same 1.0 version number but should list this under "What's New".

Comment: I am curious how "cannot accept an answer" was not caught during QA. Seems like pretty basic functionality, not exactly an esoteric use case.

Comment: @Snowman I messed with the boolean logic around showing the different possible buttons in our data-binding setup last minute. I should've set a code freeze on the app after we did our last user functionality testing session.

Comment: Re-publishing apps from updated source without changing the version number is bad practice – confusing to end users and inviting more developer mistakes. A hotfix like this should have been built and published as 1.0.1 or similar. Holding yourself and your team to proper practices like semantic versioning will make it that much easier not to make more of the kind of mistake this hotfix existed to fix in the first place.