# Can we have Meta support with the new Stack Overflow app?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app, stack-overflow-app

Any link I click to that would normally take me to Meta causes me to open the post in the Stack Exchange app instead.  I'd like a fluid and cohesive experience with the new app, and Meta is central to that experience.

Would it be possible to add Meta support?

Comment: Or maybe just make a better mobile browser experience...

Comment: Or fix the existing app...

Comment: Similarly, as I am only active on SO, I don't want to install the stackexchange app. I only use the iOS mobile app to read notifications and add comments. But whenever I receive, a notification from Meta SO, I am redirected to the browser. This feature should really be added.