# Will users be able to beta test new versions of the Stack Overflow app like the Stack Exchange app?

Tags: discussion, ios-app, stack-overflow-app

Anyone can sign up to receive early builds of the Stack Exchange iOS app through TestFlight ([Stack Exchange iOS app beta moving to Test Flight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270528/242209)).  Will the same be available as updates begin to roll out for the Stack Overflow iOS app?

Comment: Isn't the new app just the same as the old app with a different skin? This coming from someone who has not installed the app yet, just read the article.

Comment: @AshleyMedway I believe it's a stripped-down version of the existing app with different UI, and (potentially?) different features in the future.  Just curious if the same approach is going to be taken with this app as well.

Comment: Why not just fix and improve the existing app? splitting off SO is a dumb idea.

Comment: @JAL I guess my point being if you test one are you inherently testing the other, minor UI issues aside.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan Feel free to add your commentary on that in the main announcement [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349255/2415822).

Comment: @AshleyMedway What if someone wants a first look at new features in the Stack Overflow app?  I also imagine that with different UI/code, bugs willa rise that the dev team will want feedback on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put instructions for signing up here: [Help test the Stack Overflow iOS app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349721/help-test-the-stack-overflow-ios-app)

Comment: Thanks Brian.  Just a random note: when coming into this post from a push notification and tapping on the link in this answer, the Stack Exchange app crashed.