# Help test the Stack Overflow iOS app

Tags: discussion, ios-app

The [Stack Overflow iOS app](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/16/stack-overflow-official-app-launches-ios-android/) is out and I'd like to get a beta tester pool set up similar to [the one for the Stack Exchange app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270528/stack-exchange-ios-app-beta-moving-to-test-flight).

Beta testers are really important for the iOS app because we don't have as quick of a release cycle as web.  Beta testers have a chance to validate that bugs their are fixed and find bugs in new features before they go to production.

Like with the Stack Exchange app, I'll be using TestFlight to push out builds.  To install the app you will need iOS 9 or above.

## How to sign up

1. [Fill out your info in this Google Form.](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSclnZnmgi_k3dKpYfs4A7LbrGi5QQNdL3GAPB3nOTCaEmKc3A/viewform?usp=sf_link)
2. Wait for an email from Apple with the subject "TestFlight: Stack Exchange, Inc invited you to test Stack Overflow".  This won't happen right away.  Generally speaking, I'll add new testers when I push out a new build.
3. Follow the instructions in the above email to download TestFlight (if you don't already have it) and use TestFlight to download the app.

## How to report bugs

Bugs can be reported as questions tagged [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app)[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) either here or on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com). There's no built-in bug reporter or MSO support yet so you'll have to report it in a browser or through the Stack Exchange app for now.

## How does this relate to the Stack Exchange app beta?

You can be a tester for both apps, or either, or neither.  For the most part, bugs caught in one app will apply to both, so I would just test the app you want to use.  If you want to test the Stack Exchange app, [there's a separate Google Form for that](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeCOB3qyWG0XcpFzXBP1wrvVv3GtHYC9r0xBrBGB4rNdT4r4g/viewform).

Comment: Hey Brian, the build on TestFlight expired.  Any chance you can put up a new one?  Or are no new releases planned and I should just switch to the App Store version.

Comment: @JAL Oh no! They switched to 90 days so I thought I had more time, but I never pushed out a new version of the SO app.  I'll do that today.