# Mobile App Usage Stats

Tags: discussion, android-app, ios-app

This question is a direct result of the recent release of a Stack Overflow mobile app and the community's response to the announcement. In the course of the discussion, the community has expressed its dissatisfaction with the release and mentioned several reasons why. These include lack of updates and bug fixes to the existing Stack Exchange mobile app, duplication and reduced functionality of the new app compared to the old one, and the confusion around the need for "Stack Overflow" vs. "Stack Exchange", when the existing app appears as the top search result for either.

In the course of the discussion, I asked if we could get some specific usage statistics.

I've compiled a list of data points that I think would help everyone better understand how the mobile app is used.

For most of these statistics, I imagine that there is difference between the iOS and Android versions. It may be helpful to present that break down.

---

- Compared to total downloads of the application, how often is the app utilized to post a question, answer or comment versus "just browsing"?
- What is the reputation break down of the users that are posting content?
- How often is the mobile app used to perform a moderation task? While the app doesn't have access to the review queues, it does have the ability to flag questions, answers and comments. How often is that functionality used?
- How many inbox notifications are sent to a mobile application?
- How many of these notifications are acknowledged via the app versus a web browser?
- How many of the notifications that are acknowledged via the app have the user's next action (posting a question, answer or comment) occur within the app versus a web browser? There probably needs to be a time limit on this next action occurring. Let's say the notification is acknowledged and the user does something within 30 minutes. What I'm looking for with this specific data point is how often users are using the app for one of the use cases mentioned in the announcement thread - using the app only for its notification of a new inbox message.
- What is the breakdown of usage across the sites on the network?

Comment: I still hold that it's more the power users and less the whole community which are expressing their dissatisfaction right now.  Although, it'd be an interesting corollary to see what percentage of power users (those who have taken ~500 moderation actions, not necessarily *just* close votes) have used the app compared to normal users.

Comment: "How often is the mobile app used to perform a moderation task" is probably skewed by missing features driving users to a mobile browser instead. I'm one of them. Also the usefulness of push notifications can't be measured that way, at least not for me: I get a notification with the SE logo, I bring up my browser 99% of the time (I have all my tabs open all the time), not the SE app (the 1% I accidentally click the actual notification).

Comment: @Mat'sMug: and I want to avoid tapping the notification *anyway* because that marks everything in my inbox as read by linking to the inbox instead of to the post. I use Stackpop on my OSX desktop to get me the same notifications there and they *link directly to the post affected*, far more useful.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question! I have stats and code for compiling some of these stats, the rest (like the acknowledging notifications --> next action) will take a bit longer to pull. I'll post an answer on this with the items I already have results for in an hour or so.

Comment: I just want to add that the usage stats will be certainly interesting and perhaps illuminating, but (at least for Android) will be heavily biased.  I don't use the app much, but I *would* if it worked better, and I'm not even talking about moderation tasks. I can't easily browse a tag of interest for questions to answer because "back" makes me start all over (as per [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302115/back-button-goes-two-steps-back) two year old bug report and others I've seen).

Answer (score 35):

Starting with the easy to answer ones:

> Compared to total downloads of the application, how often is the app utilized to post a question, answer or comment versus "just browsing"?

Lots of ways to calculate this one. An easy one is comparing the `question.show` and `comment.submit` events in our internal metrics (so please excuse the text clashing).

Here are those for Android, from 01/01/2017 --> 05/14/2017:
[image: android question.show vs comment.submit]

And for iOS:[image: ios question.show vs comment.submit]

Comment submission is more common than question or answer creation, so I'm displaying those on the graph.

Aggregate data including post submissions:

Android:

- `question.show`: 1,071,988 sessions
- `comment.submit`: 66,087 sessions
- `question.answered`: 14,897 sessions
- `question.asked`: 11,011 sessions

iOS:

- `question.show`: 410,375 sessions
- `comment.submit`: 45,474 sessions
- `question.answered`: 9,776 sessions
- `question.asked`: 5,747 sessions

Ignoring that the three creation actions are probably not all distinct sessions, summing those sessions up and dividing by the non-creation action gives us a rough `8.6%` (Android) and `15%` (iOS) rate of "Number of sessions with create actions divided by number of sessions that looked at questions".

So, around 10% of the time, the app is used to create content.

---

> What is the reputation break down of the users that are posting content?

I don't have any easy way of figuring this out for people who are posting content. The metrics I showed above are anonymized, so there's not an easy way to find "Users who are posting from mobile".

I can however, figure out the reputation breakdown for mobile users in general.

Our push notification token database has 354,840 unique Accounts worth of active push tokens in it. I took a random sampling of 10,000 of those accounts and found each of those account's top site user (if any). Then I split up the users into buckets of reputation, and here's that graph:

[image: reputation breakdown]

The aggregate numbers which compose that graph:

- 1: iOS: 594, Android: 1646, Both: 40
- 2 - 101: iOS: 849, Android: 1835, Both: 77
- 102 - 1,000: iOS: 604, Android: 1133, Both: 82
- 1,001 - 2,500: iOS: 144, Android: 309, Both: 28
- 2,500 - 30,000: iOS: 134, Android: 259, Both: 34
- >30,000 Reputation: iOS: 12, Android: 30, Both: 4

The numbers don't add up to 10,000 because there were some accounts which have logged into the app but never interacted with any of the content on any sites, so they don't have any site users.

---

> What is the breakdown of usage across the sites on the network?

Sorry for the messy graph, it's from our internal metrics. This is the breakdown of `question.show` events on Android from 01/01/2017 to 05/14/2017.

[image: android site breakdown]

For iOS:

[image: ios site breakdown]

The sites are ordered on the right in order of usage, so on Android and iOS both Stack Overflow is the most used community, with Math Stack Exchange next, but Android users use Ask Ubuntu and Super User more than iOS users.

---

> How many inbox notifications are sent to a mobile application?

For this and the related questions I don't have any answers to give you right now.

We don't have analytics around "Push notification received" in the apps, so I'd have to look at the HTTP logs of the push server but they communicate with Google and Apple via weird setups, and each HTTP call does not imply 1 push notification, so it's kind of a mess.

I'll talk to my coworkers and see if anyone has ideas on how to pull metrics around that.

---

Two more graphs which you didn't ask for but I think might be interesting.

From the same `comment.submit` and `question.answered` events in the first part of this question, if we sum those creation events up and count the number of unique sessions per month that included at least 1 of those events, we end up with a graph of the # of active posters using the apps.

Those graphs, for Android and iOS:

[image: Android number of active users who create content]

[image: iOS number of active users who create content]

These two graphs definitely show that if we work on the apps more, the # of people using them to create content grows. The lines flattening out after Q1 2016 are definitely caused in part by lack of app updates.

The lack of a big discrepancy between the growth rates on Android and iOS makes me think that's not the *biggest* contributing factor though, since our iOS app received a lot more love in 2016 than the Android one did.

These two graphs (and the absolute numbers in the Y axis) both help convince me that adding more functionality and features to the Stack Exchange app wouldn't move the metrics enough to justify investing in them more (especially given our current company goals). More on that [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296068/229741), if you're interested.

Comment: The few things that I find most interesting - 1.) The break down of top sites between iOS and Android 2.) How few of the higher rep users really do use the app. I know it's been mentioned before, but 46 users total in the 30K+ range. Wow, that's *way* lower than I would have guessed. Even the less than 500 for the much larger range of 2,500 to 30,000 is low. 3.) Android has a higher user base than iOS.

Comment: Please allow for some of my potential bias to shine through with this follow up request: What percentage of those posts (question or answer) that are posted via that app remain on the site with a 0+ score after a week?

Comment: Thank you for sharing these stats. It's very interesting to see the actual trends behind it. That being said, it seems like the original app was pretty well received but sort of hit a plateau around the start of last year. Given that, what made SO decide to create a new app rather than update the existing one? Creating a stripped down, SO-focused version of the same app just seems like a strange decision to me given the previous apps reception even without constant updates.

Comment: @MikeC all of our ideas for updates that could point the app towards the company's goals (which have changed since 2014) didn't really fit into the SE app as a first party thing. like I can't put Stack Overflow Jobs inside of an app where the main page is hot questions from Gaming. The numbers for the apps aren't awful but at our scale and our current focus, there's no fertile ground for KPIs to try to optimize in those apps.

Comment: The reputation breakdown chart should be compared against the website's figures (using accounts active in, say, last 90 days). Not sure why not *all* usable accounts were used in the sampling though, and the rep buckets should probably match the privs buckets... and then I'd want to see % of users per bucket that use the SE app, and chart *that*; that way we would have much more comparable per-bucket figures, and I'm not convinced the lower buckets would be as over-represented as they appear here, although under-representation of priv'd users gets my point across: app needs the tools.

Comment: @Mat'sMug when you say "not _all_ usable accounts were used in the sampling" do you mean "why there was a sampling?", does all == 354,840? I skipped over that part, but basically the only way I have to look up "on which site does this Account have the most reputation, and what is it?" involves manual SQL querying, and querying for all 300,000 would take most of my day.

Comment: Yeah... I must be missing something then... in my mind querying a subset of records, or querying a whole table, involves pretty much the same SQL - if anything the sampling logic makes it more complicated. [This old query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/160371/distribution-of-avid-users-by-reputation-tier) (known as the "Grace Note Query" by CR veterans) uses the old beta-privs thresholds, but returns in less than 2 seconds against the SO db on SEDE. Is it a cross-db performance issue?

Comment: @Mat'sMug the PushTokens table of the Mobile only has the AccountIds. I then need to look up the top NetworkUser for each of those accounts, the information of which lives in a different database. To do that, i was doing queries like `SELECT .. FROM NetworkUsers WHERE AccountId IN ([batch of 500 AccountIds from my sample])`. I was doing that by hand in SSMS, but I could batch up code to do it for all users, maybe. --- I'm more than happy to do the analysis again, but I have to also do some app bug fixes today.

Comment: TBH SO should have a BI/data specialist position responsible for some ETL process that builds a high-performance dedicated database out of the many sources, comes up with reports and analysis, and to whom you (we?) could request ad-hoc queries/reports (I'm slightly biased though... that's what I do for a living) - anyway I think `WHERE AccountId IN` would perform better (and be more maintainable) if the ID's were inserted into a table and `INNER JOIN`ed instead ;-)

Comment: I find these graphs very hard to interpret without comparison to the desktop site. question.show trumps content submission, sure, but doesn't it also do the same on the desktop site? The quantity of real interest is the fraction (content submission)/(content show) for app users vs registered users on the desktop site.

Comment: Hey @KasraRahjerdi, can you also pull the fraction of users that register and post their first post without ever interacting with the desktop site for each site? Maybe monthly.