# The Stack Overflow mobile app should allow re-opening a question

Tags: feature-request, questions, vote-to-reopen, ios-app

The option for voting to close a question is available, but should we want to vote to reopen, the feature is not there:

[image]

Now this feature is missing in the Stack Exchange app also. Moving forward however can this be implemented into the new Stack Overflow app?

I've been made aware that this is because the functionality hasn't been exposed in the API. Is this something that can be exposed so that it can be implemented into the Stack Overflow app?

It seems a little backwards to have to open the question in Safari to vote to reopen. The point of an app for user experience and so you don't have to go to the browser, is it not?

Comment: The same way you do on the Stack Exchange app, which is the way which the api allows, which is none.

Comment: It's bit backwards to click _Share_ then _Open in safari_ just to reopen when the feature vote to close has been implemented. With the new app, it would make sense to implement such features to make it better.

Comment: Again, the problem is the API, not the app. The app uses the api, but the API doesn't expose this functionality.

Comment: And writing in that functionality into the API isn't something that can be done?

Comment: But not what your FR is about... you presume that this feature is missing somehow, I am just informing you that there are series of previous steps to be done before it is even implemented. As she said, the problem is not the button.

Comment: I'm sure the powers that be will understand what I'm trying to get at and not that I have to create two FRs; one to expose this in the API and the another to implement it into the app. That seems a little counterproductive.

Comment: [Related - on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233669/175248); an outstanding request from about 3 years ago to allow us to do this very thing.  For context, both the Stack Exchange app and Stack Overflow app use the same backend.

Comment: @Braiam Whether or not the app uses the public API is an *implementation detail*. This is a feature request for the app: Support reopening questions. How they implement it is irrelevant. There's nothing stopping them from using the same endpoint as the web pages; you can't expect people who raise feature requests to also dictate how it should be implemented.

Comment: Perhaps it's time to create a new API for internal use only, rather than using the publicly-available API?

Comment: And this is [why I only use the mobile site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349271/2370483). The app only supports closure (and does a terrible job at even that)

Comment: @Machavity [yup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349355/1188513).