# Link to Stack Overflow Android app from the Stack Overflow mobile view's footer

Tags: feature-request, android-app, mobile-web, footer

In the Stack Overflow mobile view, the footer is displaying with the "**Download the Stack Exchange Android app**" for the Android phones.

Since we have a [separate Android app for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android) and [separate footer for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/27/new-stack-overflow-footer-pages-launch-today/). So in the Stack Overflow footer of the mobile view's footer can we change the text to "**Download the Stack Overflow Android app**" and link it to the respective Play Store location in the Android phones.

[image: SO Mobile Footer]