# Why is there a mobile app?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-app

In most cases I prefer to use my browser over specific mobile apps. This is because browsers have lots of useful features that are missing in mobile apps:

- No install, no cluttering of device app list
- Search text on page
- URL to share for **any** page, not just the ones that the app author thought of
- Back and forward buttons
- Page visit history
- Copy and paste from page
- Zoom in/out
- Request desktop version to get access to all features
- Integration with accessibility tools? (This is a guess. I don't use any)

There may be more that I've forgotten.

Many perfectly good websites are following a trend of offering mobile apps that give a few benefits (usually notifications), but in doing so we lose out on all of the general benefits of the web listed above. They are also increasingly nagging people to switch over to the app. When I visit SO on mobile I sometimes get a big pop-up where I have to carefully select the option in small text that says something like: "No. Use the mobile site instead"

I recently noticed the new SO "Instant app" on Android, which is even worse because it starts without permission, just to give you a worse version of the site: It has some weird styling not consistent with SO and none of the benefits listed above.

I really don't understand this trend. Are actual users keen to switch over to apps? Why?

What does an SO app give you over the website that couldn't be achieved with a home screen web link, except for notifications? What if the mobile app was just reduced to something that provides notifications that open links in the system browser? Can anyone make a reasoned defence for a mobile app for reading questions? What am I missing?

Comment: "No install, no cluttering of device app list" in b4 Stack Overflow becomes a PWA

Comment: _What if the mobile app was just reduced to something that provides notifications that open links in the system browser?_ That happens when you get a meta notification anyway

Comment: Just FYI, there's also the Stack Exchange app.  I use it to read the Hot Network Questions while taking a dump.  I find it renders faster than using a browser, and the tappable areas are larger (not just the text of a link), but it certainly has its quirks (being unable to sort answers by 'active' makes it pretty useless for following meta questions that accumulate lots of answers).

Comment: I use the Stack Exchange app more than the website. It’s actually my go-to if I’m standing in lines or waiting. It’s fun to read randomized interesting questions and answers from different exchanges. The breath of knowledge that people are willing to share out there is nothing short of astounding.

Comment: I'd love for it to simply be a notification provider.

Comment: @KevinB That is pretty much the only thing I use it for. Its only a matter of time until some user makes that. We have no shortage of devs with spare time here.

Comment: Because it is trendy to use an app. All the cool kids design and use apps. Using a web browser is sooo 2014.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1174/

Comment: a mobile app can collect more user data information than a browser could! :\

Comment: I travel with public transportation each day for 1.5 to 2 hours. I love the mobile app during that time. I do however think it would be great to integrate chat into the app. I sometimes find myself wanting to chat with like-minded people while going to work, which I can't because the app doesn't support it. It's not a replacement for a real browser version of SO but a great alternative if no notebook is around. Edit: I can chat, but only through the browser and that doesn't seem to work very well on my mobile. This comment was written inside the app.

Comment: @JanDoggen https://xkcd.com/1367/ seems relevant, as well

Comment: Am I missing someone else posting jeff atwood's article against apps: https://blog.codinghorror.com/app-pocalypse-now/

Comment: What I find problematic is the obvious bad formatting of questions posted from the app. It is useful for reading but terrible for posting from.

Answer (score 16):

The Stack Exchange iOS app (and probably the Stack Overflow iOS app as well, as it's built from the same source code) does have a few things you mention:

- Page visit history (in the hamburger menu)
- Copy and paste from page
- Integration with accessibility tools

Also, the following things don't work on the mobile website, but they do in the app:

- Flagging comments
- Preview of content you're posting / editing
- Full screen code blocks
- Searching; on mobile web, this is impossible if you have the keyboard shortcuts enabled
- Lock screen widget with Hot Questions

It's well known the Android app gets less attention than the iOS one (read: almost none), and it has even been hinted that it will be discontinued in favor of a better mobile website.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I've never noticed an app that you can copy text from. The second list sounds like things that could be implemented on mobile web, though it might be difficult for various reasons. It seems like the only thing fundamentally impossible right now is notifications?

Comment: Yes (and the widget, as I just realized). But that's true (in theory) for *all* mobile apps. The first iPhone didn't even have the possibility to install custom apps. Still, apps have been very successful, mainly because they give a richer/better user experience than mobile websites.

Comment: For the record, I use the mobile site quite often as well (mainly because reviewing doesn't work in the app; clicking on links, I often end up in the mobile site).

Comment: You say that but I still think it's usually a poorer/worse experience for applications that are a good fit for web :) Maps etc. are another matter.

Comment: Yes, YMMV, and while there are objective criteria to prefer an app above a website (or vice versa), it's also partially a matter of taste.

Comment: I can flag comments just fine on my phone in the browser, same for searching (i just press a button in my browser so no keyboard shortcuts even involved). Whenever I don't see something I need I just request a desktop version, the app can't do that :)

Answer (score 15):

The Android app is really useful for receiving push notifications, which are missing from the browser.

Other than that, two features that are only available in the app are auto complete for replying to comments, and the ability to see up/down votes separately.

In general though, the mobile website has much more functionality than the app, like the ability to delete/undelete reopen, etc.

Comment: Web apps do support push notifications using the [Push API](https://w3c.github.io/push-api/).

Comment: On the website, users with 1,000 rep can "View upvote and downvote totals" by clicking on the overall score.

Comment: @RandyLevy Not on the *mobile* website.

Comment: @DheerajV.S.  That's true, I meant the mobile website of stack overflow specifically.

Answer (score 9):

I'm to go out on a limb and say that responsive design has significantly reduced the point of having a separate app in many cases, including for Stack Overflow. At this point, many apps are little more than a mobile site that you have to install and periodically update (ahem, Amazon.com). Yes, you do have things like push notifications, but in this case that's not all *that* critical of a feature.

The most successful apps are the ones that are able to provide significant functionality that would be difficult or impossible to deliver with a simple mobile site.

I think that companies in general need to have serious conversations about whether their mobile apps are providing value over and above what you can provide with responsive design. If the mobile site looks/feels like you're merely repackaging your mobile site, then consumers will have little incentive to install it.

Answer (score 8):

Back when Stack Overflow announced their *second* app, [I had a bit of a remark to the community to bring what its scope was back into context](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349324/1079354).

In summary:

- It's meant for the 80% of users who want to quickly look at the site
- It's meant to handle simple things, like simple question and answer posting, as well as simple close voting and the like
- It's ***not*** meant for power users; namely, those of us who do moderation on content, review queues, and use chat
- It focuses only on the relevant content that the standard user would want to see, and *nothing else*

Mobile apps hold advantages over mobile websites in that they are less than a button tap away; for those slightly more advanced users that know how to turn webpages into apps, it's probably a moot point, but again, think of the 80-20 rule here.  Apps also get around the issue of inconsistent presentation and compatibility issues.  Not every Android phone uses the same WebKit browser, even if their versions are *exactly* the same; they may be tweaked by the phone vendor to do some *other* thing.  With an app, you present a [much!] more unified experience to your end users.

Don't get me wrong; [I think a mobile/responsive design would be awesome](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354132/1079354).  It just doesn't seem like the rest of the community thinks that way yet.

Answer (score 5):

It's quite surprising that no answer has mentioned that the Web apps have [support for push notifications](https://w3c.github.io/push-api/). With [PWA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_app) features, it is increasingly difficult to justify a need for native mobile applications. Of course, the elephant in the room is ([cough](http://caniuse.com/#feat=push-api)) Apple ([cough](http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers)).

Comment: But then you asked _"What does an SO app give you ... except for notifications?"_. So just wanted to point out that web apps can give you that as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Android app on a day-to-day basis and I **love** its widget. Of course there are things that could be improved, especially platform integration wise (the strong side of native apps). And if the app ever gets sunsetted (sadly I know now what that means), I hope there will be a community version I can contribute to.