# Opt out of mobile app nags and Instant App

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-app

I asked the question: ["Why is there a mobile app?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355140/4284627). The consensus seems to be that there are pros and cons to using a mobile app depending on use case. It's certainly not a clear win for everyone or even most people.

So can we choose to do a one-time opt-out of all popups about the mobile app and the "Instant App" for Android that launches for SO links without asking?

Comment: That would violate one of core principles of app promotion: [No, but ask me again every time](https://xkcd.com/1174/)

Comment: Why would these minor issues matter so much that you'd feel the need to make a meta post about it..?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ:  Because pestering and abusing the community is ***wrong***!

Comment: Psh... melodrama.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Well it's freakin annoying. "No, you stupid website, I wouldn't have come here in the browser if I didn't want to _use_ the browser so _stop asking me!_" Not that I've ever seen SO ask me, but you know, if it did I'd be annoyed.

Comment: @Clonkex Well, all I do is "Request Desktop Version" and I never have to see that popup ever again.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I've never seen the popup at all and I don't request desktop version. Maybe I'm not looking in the right place ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I don't want to use the desktop version of the site on mobile most of the time. I do get the nag pop-up from time to time. But recently I ALWAYS get the Instant App on Android, which has the worst of both the web and mobile as far as I can tell. So it's definitely worth a post.

Comment: I don't think it's SE issue, but more of Google issue: "*When you tap a link, Google Play checks if there’s an app that could open the link. It will open the link in the instant app (if available) if you don’t already have the app installed on your device.*" https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7240211

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks. But that gives me the option to disable **all** Instant Apps, even the ones that might add value. I'm not sure that the SE one does. It can't do notifications or a widget. It doesn't even allow you to comment or answer. So I question why it is offered at all as it only degrades the user experience... unless perhaps you have a really bad web browser.

Comment: I too don't want to disable all apps. I wish there was a way to just get rid of it for this site.

Comment: Still no answer on how to block the ads.

Comment: @ゼーロ The point is that there is no answer because this problem is caused by google and can only be fixed by google (or complete removal of the app from google's instant app system). Unfortunately this is just the way it is.

Comment: This question is supposed to be a duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356415/how-to-prevent-notifications-about-the-new-so-instant-app-when-viewing-posts-on so it should answer the spam issue too

Comment: @ゼーロ The point is that there **is no answer** because this **problem is caused by google** and can only be fixed **by google** (or complete removal of the app from google's instant app system). Unfortunately **this is just the way it is**.

Comment: Google doesn't generate the annoying banner ads, that's an SE issue.

Comment: @TinyGiant Actually I think the [instant app should be withdrawn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355715) until it provides any benefits at all over the mobile site **and** Google allow opt-out per instant app. It doesn't make sense that SE have released a barrier to the web app that is inferior.

Answer (score 3):

> So can we choose to do a one-time opt-out of all popups about the mobile app and the "Instant App" for Android that launches for SO links without asking?

[Once Instant App is distributed by the developer](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7381861), the control is passed to [Google Play Store and Android end-user](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7240211), which means that it's out of developer's hand to customize the behavior of the popup (read: it's Google's doing).

Since it's now an Android end-user problem, there's a question on our sister site, Android.SE: [How to stop web page from opening Android Instant App?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/180234)

**Disclosure**: I wrote the answer, and I need feedback.

---

> You have <s>2</s> only 1 option:
>
> 1. **Disable the whole instant apps feature**. From [Google's Official Support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7240211),
>
> **Turn instant apps on or off**
>   You can choose whether you want to use Instant Apps. If you change your mind, you can change the setting:
>
> 1. On your device, open the Settings app [image: Settings].
> 2. Go to Google [image: Google Search] > **Instant Apps**.
> 3. Move the toggle to opt in or out.
>
> <s>2. **Disable/enable specific app**.</s>
>
> 1. Navigate to the Instant Apps setting (follow above step)
> 2. Select the app you want to enable/disable (e.g. Stack Exchange)
> 3. Select *Supported links*
> 4. Under *Opening supported links*, select *Don't open in this app*.
>
>    **IMPORTANT NOTE**: **This method is untested**. I don't have devices to test instant apps. However, [based on this article](https://9to5google.com/2017/02/11/how-to-opt-in-and-use-android-instant-apps-currently-rolling-out-to-select-devices/), I *think* the app info layout is the same as the installed app. Thus, I *assume* the dropdown is there. **Please let me know if it is possible/successful**.
>
>    Doesn't work :(

Comment: Method 2 doesn't work because Supported Links is read-only on that settings page.

Comment: I still don't know of a single benefit of the SE Instant App over the mobile site, so I wonder why it exists. Perhaps it should be withdrawn.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox thanks for informing me. Yeah, I think I can agree that it should be withdrawn instead if it's inferior to full app & mobile web. Dunno if it worths a new meta post to withdraw the Instant App...

Comment: I'm new to meta. I have no idea if anything I wrote here has been read or considered by an SE employee or anyone that can make a difference, so I wonder if I'll be wasting my time. Do meta posts actually lead to changes?

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox they do, [sometimes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app+or+ios-app+status-completed), always allow for [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) before becoming impatient...