# Withdraw the Android Instant App

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

If you don't use the Android app then SE links always launch in the "Instant App" without asking.

The Instant App has far fewer features than the mobile website or the full app. Most of the actions that seem to be available on the screen just show a prompt to install the full app.

Every time the instant app launches, I have to go to Android notifications, maybe expand the SE notification if I have several other notifications visible, and then tap "GO TO WEB".

On my phone at least, the mobile website provides a much better experience than the Instant App so it's frustrating that I am forced to go through these extra steps every time I visit the site just because [I prefer the mobile site to the full Android app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355140/why-is-there-a-mobile-app).

Instant Apps cannot be disabled individually on Android. You can either use them all or disable them all. I don't wish to disable them in case some useful ones appear. So far Stack Exchange is the only Instant App I've seen, but I would want to opt out of it even if it was as good as the full Android app, because SE is such a good fit for the web and the mobile site is great.

Therefore I suggest withdrawing the Instant App until Android allows disabling individual Instant Apps **and** the Instant App is improved to provide any benefit over the mobile site.

Comment: I don't see why the instant app can't just be a version of the mobile site with more cache control.

Comment: "show a prompt to install the full app" - Instant apps should not nag the user to install the full app. [Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KImzvcrBfzE)

Comment: @SeinopSys Like so? https://xkcd.com/1174/

Comment: If only there were some way in web applications to store information in the browser that would be available for the server-side program the next time the user visited. You could call it a "biscuit" or something.

Comment: I disabled instant apps entirely, SO was the trigger. The whole concept seems utterly pointless to me.

Comment: @Flexo: Not an Android user, so I don't know if there's more to Instant Apps than [what Google says](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html): allowing fully (?) functional native apps to run without installation. Whatever Stack Overflow made seems to fly completely in the face of that. Coming from a software company, that's honestly embarrassing.

Comment: The Stack Overflow was [really badly received](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android) at -232 votes when it was announced. Now we are basically *forced* to use the app!? Frankly this is a little bit ...big brother-y (to use a mild, non-insulting term not to needlessly upset Kasra).

Comment: @Sklivvz This has absolutely nothing to do with the Stack Overflow app. It is an instant app for the Stack Exchange app.

Comment: @JoeFriend nevertheless, it's still something that should not have been done.

Comment: In fact, if anything, the Stack Exchange app is even worse: I can't check right now, but if I am redirected to the instant app on a site I moderate ...I can't moderate it, because the app has no features for moderation (whereas the mobile site does)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We've shut down our Instant App. Sorry about the trouble, and thank you for the feedback.

Longer form answer:

We implemented Instant Apps for the Stack Exchange app almost a year before we started working on the Stack Overflow app. The Instant App ran as part of the SE app, but only for `stackoverflow.com` posts.

Once the SO app came out, this already put us on weird footing. It would take around a week of work to make an Instant App for the SO app, but I'd still need to go back and make the SE Instant App work on sites other than SO.

It was also supposed to be a bit more "magical" than the actual end-user experience. I'm not 100% sure if this is on me misunderstanding the platform or if the code I wrote wasn't right or if it required some extra server-side stuff I didn't manage to finish, but the Instant App is definitely a subpar experience.

Meanwhile, Google's asked for some changes to our Instant App for Android Oreo, users (like you) aren't super happy with the status quo, and the [mobile team is working full-time with the DAG team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/229741), and if I were to find the time to work on the Instant App I should *really* be fixing the root issues instead of just adding in new features --- as a result: We left a degraded experience as the default opt-in for users! Very bad!

I apologize for that, I should've shut it down sooner.

Thanks for bringing this issue up!

Comment: Thank you for recognising this as an issue and fixing it.