# I am solely registered via Facebook and I am trying to login to the Stack Overflow app but the option to login to Facebook does not appear:

Tags: bug, android-app, stack-overflow-app

I am migrating this issue from the Stack Exchange Meta website [Unable to login to Stack Overflow app with Facebook login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302716/unable-to-login-to-stack-overflow-app-with-facebook-login/302718#302716)
since this is an issue with the Stack Overflow Android application specifically.

I am solely registered via Facebook and I am trying to login to the Stack Overflow app but the option to login to Facebook does not appear:

[image: Faulty Login Screen]

My problem is almost identical to that posted here:

[Login with Facebook using Stack Exchange Android App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230998/login-with-facebook-using-stack-exchange-android-app/302696?noredirect=1#comment984492_302696)

except that I do have the Facebook app installed and logged into. I have tried reinstalling the Facebook app but this has not helped. Since I have registered with Facebook this means I am unable to use the application.

After comments left by Shadow Wizard I tried using the Stack Exchange Android application and was able to login. However, the "Login with Facebook" option does not not appear as an option on the Stack Overflow application.

Comment: OpenID has been a big fat failure.  You'd better create yourself a StackExchange account while you got the chance.

Comment: Yeah, the SO app is [missing a lot more than a FB login](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android/349271#349271). Try using Chrome. The mobile site works so much better

Comment: I'm able to access all features I could wish for via the Stack Exchange app fortunately, but I thought I'd highlight the fault here for future reference. Looks like this app is causing a lot of lost time for peeps!

Comment: My SO login wouldn't work on the app ("incorrect login") so I had to link my Google account to my SO account (via the website) and then use the Google account to sign in to the app.

Answer (score 6):

After reading the comment written by @Shadow Wizard on Stack Exchange Meta, I have now managed to access the Stack Exchange application with little hassle as the option to login with Facebook was available. My account as registered using Facebook did not have an email associated with it and so was not initially recognised, but after adding an email through the website separately I was able to access it. I am still not able to access the Stack Overflow application, but since the Stack Exchange application provides for all of my requirements for Stack Overflow as well as all the other Stack websites, the need for a separate Stack Overflow application seems redundant.