# Wrong title in Stack Overflow Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

This looks like a minor bug in the app, **`v1.0.4`** (current version as of today).

Reproduce it this way:

1. Open the app
2. Go to *More* → *Browsing History*. Note that the title says "Browsing history"
3. Now tap *Inbox* or *Achievements* and note the title. It still says "Browsing history"

---

<sup>Overall, my experience with the app is very poor. There is a lot to be done.</sup>

Comment: was able to repro.. also a similar problem if you go through **drafts** and **favorite questions**. Normal flow shows **StackOverflow** as the header. I suppose they havent set a header for these two tabs

Comment: Yeah, I just picked one just as an example.

Comment: The Android app? You should totally drop that and try the mobile site. It's quite similar, except it actually works and is nearly feature-complete.

Comment: @CodyGray Funny you should say that! BTW, any idea how I can bring back mobile site on my chrome on android? It seems somehow I messed up my chrome

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ You need to clear app defaults for the Stack Overflow app.

Comment: @CodyGray So I thought there it might finally have favourite tags available. Of course it doesn't. The only really usable version is the Desktop version. Even in a mobile version. I am not going to type `[*fortran*]` all the time manually when the full site features a nice icon to press.

Comment: @cybermonkey I was taking about the mobile site on chrome, not the app. Any idea how I can get back the mobile site on chrome on Android?

Comment: Oh man, I just checked and sure enough, the [Meta post announcing the Stack Overflow mobile app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android) is the all time lowest-voted post on meta.stackoverflow.com. Definitely reflects the community's perception of the quality of the app.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Yes... you need to clear the defaults for the Stack Overflow app so it doesn't intercept navigation to Stack Overflow in your browser and push you into the app.

Comment: @CodyGray Its only redeeming feature is push notifications. Unfortunately if you want those you need to have an app. It's better than nothing I suppose.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree: the mobile site works well. Just a small thing: when there is a code snippet (HTML+CSS+JS), only the code is displayed, but it doesn't offer the "Run" button, that's sad!

Comment: @cybermonkey I don't even have the app in my mobile anymore, so how can that happen? Moreover, my chrome is not showing mobile site before even I installed the app. Anyway, nevermind answering my original comment.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Could it be that "Request desktop site" is enabled in your chrome settings? Touch the 3-dot menu icon and see if "Request desktop site" is checked ([example](https://www.techbout.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/switch-back-to-mobile-site-chrome-android.png))

Comment: Remember to be kind: https://twitter.com/davedelong/status/910645900950638592

Comment: @Kodos I afraid not. In fact, I toggled that a number of times should my chrome get back to its senses ;-)