# Stack Exchange app crashing on Android

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, android-app, stack-overflow-app

The Stack Exchange app is crashing on startup if I'm logged in, and has become completely useless except in the case of opening a link to anywhere other than the front page so that it is bypassed completely (it's working to submit this).

I am using Android 6.0.1 with Android System WebView and Chrome, each fully updated. I have tried clearing the app data and logging in again, and uninstalling/reinstalling the app. It seems like it's because I have a couple of notifications, but checking them through the browser didn't mark those as new so it's not helping.

This **has not** happened with [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) on the multiple occasions it's had a chance, but is happening now the first time there's a notification from Stack Overflow, which leads me to believe that somehow it/it's notifications are the issue.

Edit: Also not happening with the Stack Overflow app, though it also isn't a full app and instead opens the phone's browser for most things =\

Comment: I experienced the same crash on startup on Android 8.0.0 on Oneplus 3, running oxygenos 5.0.1

Comment: Mine is just a cheap stock Android OS/LG firmware mix -- an LG K3 aka LS450 from Boost Mobile. Not rooted, and nothing else out of the ordinary. The only thing I can think of on my end would be my crappy WiFi, but it works fine for playing Rocket League on Steam, lol.

Comment: Even if it's broken, there's not gonna be any update anytime soon for the official apps on android. So you would have to deal with it as it is, or else shift your focus to mobile webpage!

Comment: That's kind terrible -- it seems like these apps are a prime candidate for being open source, considering what they're for. Lol. May look into decompiling/fixing/recompiling it, but I don't have a Play Store license and it would likely not be legal to redistribute copies, so there wouldn't be a lot of good reason for it.

At this point it crashes every time I try to open it, so there's no chance to deal with it as is.

Thank you for the insight :)

Comment: Heh [Null Pointer Exception](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307053/se-android-app-crashes-on-opening-when-logged-in)

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android)

Comment: Same problem here, with nearly the same setup as @WayneJohnston (OP3, OxygenOS Open Beta 32, Android 8.0.0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry about this! It's fixed as of two minutes ago.

We made some changes to the backend that powered the feed to remove feed item types that are rarely seen and rarely clicked on but have upkeep for us on the back-end, and I had assumed the app was more resilient in how it handled the feed's data structure changing.

We've fixed it on the backend to replace the missing item types with empty lists of those item types, which fixes the NPE.

Comment: Clearly, the lesson here is that removing ads breaks everything.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the amazingly fast fix .