# Could we have Stack Overflow dedicated mobile application

Tags: feature-request, android-app, mobile-web

I often find myself using Stack Overflow while commuting. I also find the Stack Exchange mobile app very useful. After some time of using it, the app feels quite primitive and is lacking good UI.

**Wouldn't dedicated Stack Overflow application be better Solution?** I know that there already was such application.

**What were the reasons behind cancelling development of It?**

Comment: Eons ago, it was a priority for them. The [reception around it, though,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349255/1079354) was probably enough to scare them out of investing any more time or energy into its development.

Comment: I highly recommend the old mobile website https://stackoverflow.com , scroll down "mobile". That's what works for me. I honestly don't think that there is a need for a standalone app, as the site requires a lot of internet requests, so there is not much benefit of having a standalone application, also most people visit this site via the desktop website.

Comment: I think it'd be great to have a mobile app or at least a site site that goes beyond just being responsive and configured the UI with mobile UI idioms (which generally means "minimalist" at least in a non-"advanced" view). 

It would also be a hell of a lot of work for a minimal payoff with respect to how SO is currently being used.  And it has to be a _superior_ experience to the website, at least for the common tasks.  AFAIK, the old app fell down on that front.

Answer (score 5):

Well https://stackoverflow.com is already responsive, you can visit it via your mobile phone. So what benefit would you have with a native application? I can't think of one.

Native apps really shine if you have offline capabilities or if you do heavy computations on the client - both things don't fit to SO.

I don't think that SO Inc. should waste their development time with an app that "no one" (+500.000 downloads vs. ~250 Mio webpage visits *each month*²) uses.

<sub>² according to Google Play and StackOverflow Site Analytics</sub>

Comment: Tbf, they might get more people to use the app if they actually kept it up to date and functional. The responsive design isn't fully functional either (go to any user page on a phone - it ain't responsive)

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl yeah, the "mobile" version works quite well, just the queues & snippets are missing IMO

Comment: The part I like about the app is that I can set all my most-visited sites to just show in the side drawer, which can be accessed from anywhere in the app. It's just not as convenient using the web versions.

Comment: I can think of several advantages that the native app had over the responsive site: a feed to see interesting things around the network; notifications on things in your inbox; a way to keep track of your rep in a widget if you cared about that...

Comment: For what it's worth the mobile app was good. It just didn't cater enough to power users, and announcements about it were made to... Power users.

Comment: Power users are typically the ones who will take the time to seek out, install, and use a dedicated app, @Makoto. The casual users don't have the time for or interest in that. They'll just fire it up in their browser, no installation required.

Comment: @makoto "a feed" and "notifications" can both be realized on the website. And "a widget to track rep" is not a killer feature imo.

Comment: Yes, it's *clearly* responsive. https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2gyu.jpg

Comment: @kemicofa then the solution is to fix the CSS instead of redeveloping *another* application.

Comment: @JonasWilms why redevelop an app when they already developped two different ones (StackOverflow and StackExchange)? The work was already put in. They're clean and polished. Luckily I downloaded them before they were removed and I still use them to this day. They also send me notifications. I've tried multiple times the web app on my phone, and compared to the app it's *clearly* lacking.