# Implementing reCAPTCHA might have broken the mobile site

Tags: bug, user-experience, mobile-web

I do most of my posting from the mobile site, and it seems to have been getting less and less love lately. Since the dark theme changes, random pages seemingly don't have a mobile version any more (tags list shows the desktop version all the time) and there are a couple of other occasions where some minor hasn't worked on mobile that worked on desktop, comments can't be flagged etc.

Coincidentally I've started getting [reCAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReCAPTCHA) checks from time to time on the desktop site.

Just now I was trying to answer a question on the mobile site, wrote the answer, clicked post- nothing happened at all. I clicked again, several times- no visual changes, no "data is flowing" whirling icon in the top bar of the phone (iOS 12.2 / i7).

I hit "request desktop site" to get Safari to lie about its user agent and hit post again to be greeted with a reCAPTCHA. It was particularly hard too; I asked about five different sets of questions before it went away, including two of those "keep tapping crosswalks until there are none left" and they just kept coming... I guess Google really must be unsure if I'm a robot or not, which I'm not sure is a compliment :)

Were reCAPTCHA added recently and are they a feature of the mobile site? Was mobile Post Answer being inoperative because a reCAPTCHA was required? If it was, there aren't plans to install reCAPTCHA for the mobile site, can at least a notification be added to advise the user to switch to the main site and complete a reCAPTCHA? Having the Post Answer seemingly do absolutely nothing is quite confusing.

Comment: Wow, respect. I only occasionally use the mobile site and mostly for reading. It's a hassle to do any actual posting from it. Also, as far as I'm aware the mobile site *is* left mostly untouched. I think the focus is the responsive site which is the desktop one you had to switch to with the idea that it will replace the mobile one.

Comment: I think I might be the only user left of the mobile site then! Far less cluttered UI for me, easier to navigate. I never got on with the app either.. maybe I'll just have to get used to the responsive site and then the user count can drop to 0 and SO can finally turn off mobile :)

Comment: Oh, I actually like the mobile site. I agree, it's less cluttered. For viewing, at least. I just don't like posting from it. The only feature I'm missing (and I don't think I'll get) is my saved custom filters - they don't seem to be anywhere, I have to flip over to the desktop site for those. As for the app...I'm pretty sure it's also abandoned. Twice, in fact because, [they made a second one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android).

Comment: *"I do most of my posting from the mobile site, and it seems to have been getting less and less love lately."* Yes, the mobile site is completely unmaintained. The main site has been made responsive, and that is now the recommended way of interacting with the site, even on mobile devices. I don't think reCaptcha is new; you just did something to make the system suspect you might be a bot. I hit this once in a while by moderating too efficiently.